# JFR.dump fails. "No data in specified interval"

Tags: trace, jmc, jfr

I get the following error message when executing `jcmd 115 JFR.dump name=continuous_recording`:

```
115:
Dump failed. No data found in the specified interval.
```

I started the recording with the following configuration:

```
XX:StartFlightRecording=disk=true,dumponexit=true,
filename=/home/site/diagnostics/recording.jfr,
maxsize=1024m,maxage=1d,name=continuous_recording
```

It could be that the buffer has not yet filled the minimum chunk size. But the JFR.check command does not provide that information.

**Update:**

I can get a dump from the Java app if I run JFR.dump without specifying the name of the recording. I tried encapsulating the recording name with quotes (escaped and un-escaped) and got the same error as before.

```
005c736ce3ee:/home# jcmd 115 JFR.dump filename="home/6_10_dump1.jfr"
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
115:
Dumped recording, 155.8 MB written to: /home/6_10_dump1.jfr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azul support helped figure this out. If you don't specify the filename when starting the VM, then the following works:

```
XX:StartFlightRecording=disk=true,name=continuous_recording,dumponexit=true,maxsize=1024m,maxage=1d
```

This bug was filed and fixed as JDK-8220657. Azul said they will backport this to Zulu 8 and 11 in the future.

Comment: That was what I wrote a month ago, and I (Oracle) even provided a patch https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-jfr-dev/2019-June/000632.html

Answer (score 1):

What version of the JDK are you using? The chunk should not need to be filled up.

There is a bug [1] that happens in JDK 11 or later, if you specify the filename of the file you want to dump at startup, but don't specify it when you dump the file.

Try this as a work around:

```
$ jcmd 115 JFR.dump filename=recording.jfr
```

[1] https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8220657

Comment: I'm using Azulu's Zulu JDK 8_212:
`openjdk version "1.8.0_212" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.38.0.13-linux-musl-x64)-Microsoft-Azure-restricted (build 1.8.0_212-b04) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.38.0.13-linux-musl-x64)-Microsoft-Azure-restricted (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)`

Comment: Azul is based on the JDK 11 implementation of JFR. I will look into the filled issue. It should not happen, but there could be a bug.